# AFTER DELETE Trigger is not inserting multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER 
TRIGGER [tgr_del_into_plan_audit]
ON [dbo].[agent_plan_details]
AFTER DELETE
AS 

    declare @plan_title_id int;
    declare @plan_title varchar(50);
    declare @no_of_property_listing int;
    declare @validity_of_plan int;
    declare @Each_property_listing_life int;
    declare @list_of_property_in_search_result int;
    declare @price decimal(8,2);
    declare @discount BIT;
    declare @discount_code varchar(10);
    declare @discount_percentage int

    select @plan_title_id=d.plan_title_id from deleted d;
    select @plan_title=d.plan_title from deleted d;
    select @no_of_property_listing=d.no_of_property_listing from deleted d;
    select @validity_of_plan=d.validity_of_plan from deleted d;
    select @Each_property_listing_life=d.Each_property_listing_life from deleted d;
    select @list_of_property_in_search_result=d.list_of_property_in_search_result from deleted d;
    select @price=d.price from deleted d;
    select @discount=d.discount from deleted d;
    select @discount_code=d.discount_code from deleted d;
    select @discount_percentage=d.discount_percentage from deleted d;

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO agent_plan_details_audit 
                    ( plan_title_id,
                     plan_title, 
                     no_of_property_listing,
                     validity_of_plan,
                     Each_property_listing_life,
                     list_of_property_in_search_result,
                     price,
                     discount,
                     discount_code,
                     discount_percentage,
                     create_date,
                     action )

                VALUES
                    (@plan_title_id,
                    @plan_title,
                    @no_of_property_listing,
                    @validity_of_plan,
                    @Each_property_listing_life,
                    @list_of_property_in_search_result,
                    @price,
                    @discount,
                    @discount_code,

        @discount_percentage,
                    GETDATE(),
                     'D')




END
```

Comment: And what database system is this for? Triggers aren't standardized, and the `sql` tag is for the standard SQL language. Also, since you've already written a partially working trigger, where's the code?

Comment: Show us your trigger. :)

Comment: If you'd post your current code, we might be able to fix it.

Comment: What kind of rows? Grid rows? HTML table rows? SQL rows?

Comment: @jlafay `sql` is tagged. ;)

Comment: @PLB, now it is. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

See [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG_SomeTable_Delete
    ON SomeTable AFTER DELETE
    AS
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO SomeTable(SomeColumn)
            SELECT SomeColumn FROM DELETED
        END
```

`DELETED` can contain multiple rows, so use a `SELECT` instead.

In your case:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [tgr_del_into_plan_audit]
    ON [dbo].[agent_plan_details]
    AFTER DELETE
    AS
       BEGIN
           SET NOCOUNT ON;
           INSERT INTO agent_plan_details_audit
           (
               plan_title_id,
               plan_title,
               no_of_property_listing,
               validity_of_plan,
               Each_property_listing_life,
               list_of_property_in_search_result,
               price,
               discount,
               discount_code,
               discount_percentage,
               create_date,
               action
           )
           SELECT
               plan_title_id,
               plan_title,
               no_of_property_listing,
               validity_of_plan,
               Each_property_listing_life,
               list_of_property_in_search_result,
               price,
               discount,
               discount_code,
               discount_percentage,
               GETDATE(),
               'D'
           FROM DELETED
       END
```

Answer (score 3):

[`deleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) can contain *multiple* rows. As such, assigning values from columns in it to a scalar variable is *always*<sup>1</sup> a mistake.

Try, instead:

```
ALTER 
TRIGGER [tgr_del_into_plan_audit]
ON [dbo].[agent_plan_details]
AFTER DELETE
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO agent_plan_details_audit 
( plan_title_id,
  plan_title, 
  no_of_property_listing,
  validity_of_plan,
  Each_property_listing_life,
  list_of_property_in_search_result,
  price,
  discount,
  discount_code,
  discount_percentage,
  create_date,
  action )
SELECT
  plan_title_id,
  plan_title, 
  no_of_property_listing,
  validity_of_plan,
  Each_property_listing_life,
  list_of_property_in_search_result,
  price,
  discount,
  discount_code,
  discount_percentage,
  GETDATE(),
  'D'
FROM
  deleted
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Someone's bound to point out *some* edge case where it *isn't a mistake* to have a statement like this in a trigger:

```
select @plan_title_id=d.plan_title_id from deleted d;
```

But such circumstances are by far in the minority - I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Each of those `SELECT`s in your current query will be selecting a value from an *arbitrary* row of `deleted` - it's not even guaranteed that each of the `SELECT`s would obtain a value from the *same* arbitrary row.